# Python & docker: how can i add packages into sys.path?

Tags: python, package, pythonpath, sys.path

I've tried to solve it several times but I can't find it anywhere.

Let me get it straight.

I create `game` in `C:/Users`, which is a package and composed of like

```
game/__init__.py
game/sound/__init__.py
game/sound/echo.py
```

And I execute `Test_Module.py` at other location by Pycharm

I try

```
>>> sys.path.append("C:/Users/game")
```

and

```
>>> sys.path.insert(0, "C:/Users/game")
```

and when I import game, there is red underline in Pycharm

> No module named 'game' appear in docker.

I did project Interpreter to select path as well. But it just make red underline disappear and still doesn't work

> No module named 'game'

Well, If I moved the `game` file to the folder where I execute `Test_Module.py`, it was totally working without `sys.path.append` but just `import game`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Linux so I tried to replicate your package structure like this.

```
mkdir -p game/sound
touch game/__init__.py
touch game/sound/__init__.py
touch game/sound/echo.py
```

Now my directory looks like this

```
$ tree                                                                                                                                                        
.
└── game
    ├── __init__.py
    └── sound
        ├── echo.py
        └── __init__.py
```

`echo.py` contains this

```
def hello():
    print("hello")
```

If I start the python interpreter, I can call the function

```
$ python
Python 3.6.4 (default, Jul 17 2018, 18:32:53) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from game.sound import echo
>>> dir(echo)
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'hello']
>>> echo.hello()
```

And it returns correctly

```
hello
```

I opened this in pycharm and it looks like it's finding everything correctly. If you follow what I did in a separate directory and open in pycharm, does this work for you?

Comment: Yes, it works but it happened when i append the path of package file into sys.path. i think tree of package doesn't have any problem... Or is it wrong way to write path? When print(sys.path), it is ['/sample', '/opt/conda/lib/python37.zip', '/opt/conda/lib/python3.7', '/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages', 'C:/Users/conkj/game']. And last one is the path of my package, first one that is called 'sample' is where i execute Pycharm.